# failed to compile OpenGTS , on windows8.1

Tags: java, tomcat, ant, compiler-errors

i'm having trouble compiling opengts on windows 8.1
i'm have followed OpenGTS Installation and Configuration pdf but still with no luck
i'm using

java: jdk1.7.0_45
ant : apache-ant-1.9.3
tomcat : tomcat 8
mysql : mysql5.5.20
mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin.jar
javax.mail.jar

i have configured JAVA_HOME,GTS_HOME,CATALINA_HOME,MYSQL_HOME,ANT_HOME

and added the them to the path variable

any help is appreciated.
thanks

## the output of the build is :

```
Buildfile: E:\java\projects\opengts\build.xml
clean:
[delete] Deleting directory E:\java\projects\opengts\build
custom.jar:
 [echo] Skipping General Custom build ...
customtrack.jar:
 [echo] Skipping Track Custom build ...
custom:
prepare:
[mkdir] Created dir: E:\java\projects\opengts\build
[mkdir] Created dir: E:\java\projects\opengts\build\lib
 [echo] OS = Windows 8
 [echo] JavaHome = C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
 [exec] java version "1.7.0_45"
 [exec] Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
 [exec] Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
 [copy] Copying 2 files to E:\java\projects\opengts\build\lib
 [echo] (Ignore copy 'not found' warnings)
 [copy] Warning: E:\java\projects\opengts\lib\gtsopt\classes does not exist.
  gtsutils.compile:
 [echo] Compiling gtsutils.jar source ... 
[javac] Compiling 62 source files to E:\java\projects\opengts\build
[javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
[javac] Note: E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\OSTools.java uses or    overrides a deprecated API.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[javac] 1 warning
[javac] Creating empty E:\java\projects\opengts\build\org\opengts\util\package-    info.class
 [echo] Compiling SendMailArgs.java (optional if 'mail.jar' not available) ... 
[javac] Compiling 1 source file to E:\java\projects\opengts\build
[javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:37: error: package javax.mail does not exist
[javac] import javax.mail.*;
[javac] ^
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:38: error: package javax.mail.internet does not exist
[javac] import javax.mail.internet.*;
[javac] ^
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:365: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]     private static InternetAddress[] _convertRecipients(String to[])
[javac]                    ^
[javac]   symbol:   class InternetAddress
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:366: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         throws AddressException
[javac]                ^
[javac]   symbol:   class AddressException
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:400: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]     private static void _printAddresses(String msg, Address addr[])
[javac]                                                     ^
[javac]   symbol:   class Address
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:167: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]                 InternetAddress ia = new InternetAddress(addr, true);
[javac]                 ^
[javac]   symbol:   class InternetAddress
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:167: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]                 InternetAddress ia = new InternetAddress(addr, true);
[javac]                                          ^
[javac]   symbol:   class InternetAddress
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:266: error: package javax.mail does not exist
[javac]         javax.mail.Authenticator auth = null;
[javac]                   ^
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:268: error: package javax.mail does not exist
[javac]             auth = new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
[javac]                                  ^
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:279: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
[javac]         ^
[javac]   symbol:   class Session
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:279: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
[javac]                           ^
[javac]   symbol:   variable Session
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:282: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]             MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
[javac]             ^
[javac]   symbol:   class MimeMessage
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:282: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]             MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
[javac]                                   ^
[javac]   symbol:   class MimeMessage
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:283: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]             msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
[javac]                             ^
[javac]   symbol:   class InternetAddress
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:285: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]             InternetAddress toAddr[]  = _convertRecipients(to);
[javac]             ^
[javac]   symbol:   class InternetAddress
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:286: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]             InternetAddress ccAddr[]  = _convertRecipients(cc);
[javac]             ^
[javac]   symbol:   class InternetAddress
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:287: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]             InternetAddress bccAddr[] = _convertRecipients(bcc);
[javac]             ^
[javac]   symbol:   class InternetAddress
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:296: error: package Message does not exist
[javac]                 msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO , toAddr);
[javac]                                          ^
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:297: error: package Message does not exist
[javac]                 msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC , ccAddr);
[javac]                                          ^
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:298: error: package Message does not exist
[javac]                 msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, bccAddr);
[javac]                                          ^
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:302: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]                     Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
[javac]                     ^
[javac]   symbol:   class Multipart
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:302: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]                     Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
[javac]                                               ^
[javac]   symbol:   class MimeMultipart
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:304: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]                         MimeBodyPart textBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
[javac]                         ^
[javac]   symbol:   class MimeBodyPart
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:304: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]                         MimeBodyPart textBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
[javac]                                                         ^
[javac]   symbol:   class MimeBodyPart
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:309: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]                     BodyPart attachBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
[javac]                     ^
[javac]   symbol:   class BodyPart
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:309: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]                     BodyPart attachBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
[javac]                                                   ^
[javac]   symbol:   class MimeBodyPart
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:324: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]                     Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
[javac]                     ^
[javac]   symbol:   class Transport
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:329: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]                     Transport.send(msg);
[javac]                     ^
[javac]   symbol:   variable Transport
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:338: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         } catch (MessagingException me) {
[javac]                  ^
[javac]   symbol:   class MessagingException
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:342: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]                 if (ex instanceof SendFailedException) {
[javac]                                   ^
[javac]   symbol:   class SendFailedException
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:343: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]                     SendFailedException sfex = (SendFailedException)ex;
[javac]                     ^
[javac]   symbol:   class SendFailedException
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:343: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]                     SendFailedException sfex = (SendFailedException)ex;
[javac]                                                 ^
[javac]   symbol:   class SendFailedException
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:348: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]                 ex = (ex instanceof MessagingException)? ((MessagingException)ex).getNextException() : null;
[javac]                                     ^
[javac]   symbol:   class MessagingException
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:348: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]                 ex = (ex instanceof MessagingException)? ((MessagingException)ex).getNextException() : null;
[javac]                                                            ^
[javac]   symbol:   class MessagingException
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:368: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         java.util.List<InternetAddress> inetAddr = new Vector<InternetAddress>();
[javac]                        ^
[javac]   symbol:   class InternetAddress
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:368: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         java.util.List<InternetAddress> inetAddr = new Vector<InternetAddress>();
[javac]                                                               ^
[javac]   symbol:   class InternetAddress
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:386: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]                 inetAddr.add(new InternetAddress(t)); 
[javac]                                  ^
[javac]   symbol:   class InternetAddress
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:387: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]             } catch (AddressException ae) {
[javac]                      ^
[javac]   symbol:   class AddressException
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\util\SendMailArgs.java:392: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         return inetAddr.toArray(new InternetAddress[inetAddr.size()]);
[javac]                                     ^
[javac]   symbol:   class InternetAddress
[javac]   location: class SendMailArgs
[javac] 39 errors
[javac] 1 warning
[javac] Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
 [echo] Compiling dbtools ... 
[javac] Compiling 24 source files to E:\java\projects\opengts\build
[javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
[javac] Note: E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\dbtools\DBAdmin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[javac] 1 warning
[javac] Creating empty E:\java\projects\opengts\build\org\opengts\dbtools\package-    info.class
gtsutils.exceltools:
gtsutils.sigHandler:
gtsutils.optional:
gtsutils.jar:
 [echo] Creating gtsutils.jar ... 
 [copy] Copying 14 files to E:\java\projects\opengts\build
  [jar] Building jar: E:\java\projects\opengts\build\lib\gtsutils.jar
   gtsutils:
CompileTime.java:
 [echo] Creating CompileTime module ...
  gtsdb:
 [echo] Creating gtsdb.jar ...
[javac] Compiling 112 source files to E:\java\projects\opengts\build
[javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
[javac] 1 warning
[javac] Creating empty E:\java\projects\opengts\build\org\opengts\geocoder\tinygeocoder\package-info.class
[javac] Creating empty E:\java\projects\opengts\build\org\opengts\db\tables\package-info.class
[javac] Creating empty E:\java\projects\opengts\build\org\opengts\geocoder\nominatim\package-info.class
[javac] Creating empty E:\java\projects\opengts\build\org\opengts\dbtypes\package-info.class
[javac] Creating empty E:\java\projects\opengts\build\org\opengts\geocoder\google\package-info.class
[javac] Creating empty E:\java\projects\opengts\build\org\opengts\geocoder\geonames\package-info.class
[javac] Creating empty E:\java\projects\opengts\build\org\opengts\db\dmtp\package-info.class
[javac] Creating empty E:\java\projects\opengts\build\org\opengts\geocoder\gisgraphy\package-info.class
[javac] Creating empty E:\java\projects\opengts\build\org\opengts\geocoder\package-info.class
[javac] Creating empty E:\java\projects\opengts\build\org\opengts\db\package-info.class
 [copy] Copying 45 files to E:\java\projects\opengts\build
  [jar] Building jar: E:\java\projects\opengts\build\lib\gtsdb.jar
 [copy] Copying 1 file to E:\java\projects\opengts\build\lib
optjars:
   tomcat.home:
  [echo] 'CATALINA_HOME' is defined - C:\Program Files\tomcat
 tomcat.env:
tools:
 [echo] Tools ...
[javac] Compiling 4 source files to E:\java\projects\opengts\build
[javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
[javac] E:\java\projects\opengts\src\org\opengts\war\tools\BufferedHttpServletResponse.java:41: error: BufferedServletOutputStream is not abstract and does not override abstract method setWriteListener(WriteListener) in    ServletOutputStream
[javac]     public static class BufferedServletOutputStream
[javac]                   ^
[javac] 1 error
[javac] 1 warning

BUILD FAILED
E:\java\projects\opengts\build.xml:2046: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 30 seconds
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you put the JavaMail API on the $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext/ directory?

and also, this error

> error: BufferedServletOutputStream is not abstract and does not
>   override abstract method setWriteListener(WriteListener) in
>   ServletOutputStream

is because you are using Tomcat8.x you should use Tomcat7.x

Answer (score 0):

Just uncomment the last method in BufferedServletOutputStream.java line 74 as per path in the error

> setWriteListener(/*  javax.servlert */ WriteListener)

I mean remove /* and */
and everything will work fine, even if you use tomcat 7 / 8.